# Upside down videos on BlueStacks

Tags: video, bluestacks, instagram

I use the latest version of BlueStacks as a simulator on my PC at the office.
I've installed Instagram on the BlueStacks simulator to work easier when I don't have my mobile phone with me at the office. My PC is OptiPlex 9020 - i7 and I have installed the latest version of BlueStacks.

The problem is that I see the Instagram videos upside down.

Should I change any setting?

Answer (score 0):

Because I had used it, just download BlueStacks with Android and Windows both set to the 64-bit version. Use the following link https://www.bluestacks.com/download.html.

It will 100% solve your problem, the only condition is virtualization on your PC must be enabled.